# How to log user out with Axios using authorization bearer + token

Tags: javascript, axios, jwt, fetch-api

I have an application where I log user in by connecting to backend (using axios) and getting a JWT Token which is stored in localStorage. My problem comes in with the logout functionality. I currently do this:

```
async endAuth(context) {
    try {
      await axios.post("auth/logout", {
        headers: {
         Authorization:
            "Bearer " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).token,
        },
      });
      localStorage.clear();
      context.commit("setUser", {
        token: null,
        userId: null,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      const error = new Error("Something went wrong");
      throw error;
    }
}
```

This does not work. The connection to API is established but i get a 401 error from backend with
`{success: false, message: 'Expired or Invalid Token'}`

Now I tried adding `"Content-Type": "application/json",` to the headers still no luck.

I also changed my code to use JavaScript build in `fetch()` API. And that WORKS! Here is the code:

```
async endAuth(context) {
  let url = baseURL + "/auth/logout";
  const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization:
        "Bearer " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).token,
    },
    });
    const responseData = await response.json();
    if (!response.ok) {
      const error = new Error(
        responseData.message || "Failed to authenticate. Check your login data."
      );
      throw error;
    } else {
      localStorage.clear();
      context.commit("setUser", {
        token: null,
        userId: null,
      });
    }
}
```

I also tried setting axios headers via `axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("currentUser").token;` - no luck
Am I missing something here with the axios request?

Comment: Is your API receiving the correct token? The problem seems to be at the server side if it is.

Comment: I checked the response payload and it looks correct 

`headers: {Content-Type: "application/json",…}
Authorization: "Bearer [correctToken]"
Content-Type: "application/json"`

Comment: @AyushGupta update. I've realised that the code DOES work - but only after i refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

General short solution:

```
// previus logout
this.$axios.setHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`);
// after logout
this.$axios.setHeader('Authorization', null)
```

Specific long solution (question):

```
 async endAuth(context) {
        try {
          this.$axios.setHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).token}`);
          await axios.post("auth/logout");
          localStorage.clear();
          context.commit("setUser", {
            token: null,
            userId: null,
          });
          this.$axios.setHeader('Authorization', null)
        } catch (e) {
          const error = new Error("Something went wrong");
          throw error;
        }
    }
```

This just happened to me with nuxt, I hope someone else is useful